# Eloquent Validation for composite unique key

Tags: validation, laravel, eloquent

I'm using Eloquent outside laravel framework from https://github.com/illuminate/database.
The below is my composer file

```js
{
    "require": {
        "illuminate/database": "*",
        "illuminate/validation": "*",
        "dhorrigan/capsule": "*"
    }
}
```

And because of problem in Validator::make(). I'm using one of the suggested method in stackoverflow to use it like

```php
class Validator
{

    protected static $factory;

    public static function instance()
    {
        if (!static::$factory) {
            $translator = new Symfony\Component\Translation\Translator('en');
            static::$factory = new Illuminate\Validation\Factory($translator);
        }

        return static::$factory;
    }

    public static function __callStatic($method, $args)
    {

        $instance = static::instance();

        return call_user_func_array(array($instance, $method), $args);

    }
}
```

Now i can validate required, in, etc. But i'm not able to validate unique key index for two or three columns. I tried the https://github.com/felixkiss/uniquewith-validator. But its extended from Validator. It dint work for me. And i'm not sure if laravel has a way to handle validation for composite unique keys. Their examples are not clear in the documentation.

Can you suggest a way to solve the composite unique key validation ?

Answer (score 2):

In my case **some rules** (e.g.: unique) **didn't work** since you need a presenceValidator set in your factory. I managed it and this is my approach:

**Create your own class (MyModel) extending Eloquent model and add this method:**

```
public static function getResolver()
    {
        return parent::$resolver;
    }
```

**in your validator class after namespace (easier names):**

```
use \Illuminate\Validation\Factory as Factory;

use \Illuminate\Validation\DatabasePresenceVerifier as DatabasePresenceVerifier;

use \Symfony\Component\Translation\Translator as Translator;
```

**Finally (I'm not using dhorrigan capsule but it may work):**

```
$translator = new Translator('en');
$container = $capsule->getContainer();            
$presenceVerifier = new DatabasePresenceVerifier(MyModel::getResolver());
static::$factory = new Factory($translator, $container);
static::$factory->setPresenceVerifier($presenceVerifier);
```

Now you can use unique validation rule and other rules based on DB.

Hope it helps!