# Laravel 5 Unique Validation Not Working

Tags: php, validation, laravel

I'm new to Laravel 5, supposed I have firstname and surname field on my database. I have this validation?

```
public function create()
{

    $rules = array(
        'firstname'         => 'required:unique',
        'surname'           => 'required:unique',
        'phoneno'           => 'required',
        'mcmillan'          => 'required',
        'hri'               => 'required',
        'diabetes'          => 'required',
        'breastcancer'      => 'required',
        'gpt'               => 'required',
    );

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    // Check if all fields is filled
    if ($validator->fails()) 
    {
        return Redirect::to('brk')->withErrors($validator);
    }
    else
    {
        $flag = Input::get('flag');

        /* If version 2 (Opt In) */
        if($flag == "1")
        {
            if(Input::get('opt') != "")
            {
                $optMethod = Input::get('opt');
            }
            else
            {
                $optMethod = 'OptOut';
            }
        }
        else if($flag == "0") /* If version 1 (Opt Out) */
        {
            if(Input::get('opt') != "")
            {
                $optMethod = Input::get('opt');
            }
            else
            {
                $optMethod = 'OptIn';
            }
        }

        $firstname      = Input::get('firstname');
        $surname        = Input::get('surname');
        $phoneno        = Input::get('phoneno');
        $mcmillan       = Input::get('mcmillan');
        $hri            = Input::get('hri');
        $diabetes       = Input::get('diabetes');
        $breastcancer   = Input::get('breastcancer');
        $gpt            = Input::get('gpt');

        $brk = new \App\Http\Models\BrkDailyMail;
        $brk->firstname            = $firstname;
        $brk->surname              = $surname;
        $brk->phoneno              = $phoneno;
        $brk->mcmillan             = $mcmillan;
        $brk->hri                  = $hri;
        $brk->diabetes             = $diabetes;
        $brk->breastcancer         = $breastcancer;
        $brk->gpt                  = $gpt;
        $brk->OptMethod             = $optMethod;
        $brk->hostname             = Request::root().'/brk';
        $brk->save();
        Session::flash('alert-success', 'Form Submitted Successfully.');
        /* If version 2 (Opt In) */
        if($flag == "1")
        {
            return Redirect::to('brk2');
        }
        else if($flag == "0") /* If version 1 (Opt Out) */
        {
            return Redirect::to('brk');
        }

    }

}
```

and the form is still submitting? what could be the problem? seems the validation won't work?

The form should make some errors right? but it still inserting in the database

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eloquent Validation for composite unique key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18781555/eloquent-validation-for-composite-unique-key)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$rules = array(
    'firstname' => 'required|unique:users',
    'surname'   => 'required|unique:users',
);
```

Read more:

- http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#basic-usage
- http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#rule-unique

Comment: does not work me Sir, My model is BRKDailyMails I already changed users to BRKDailyMails

Comment: you need table name here, not model name.

Comment: yes that is my model name. However I changed my questions, seems my validator doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you have a mistake here

```
'required:unique'
```

Should be

```
'required|unique'
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with Laravel 5.8. I have solved it this way.

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                    'username'     =>  "required|unique:users,username",
                    'password'   =>  "required",
                    ]
                );
```

Before this I got errors in validation from Laravel. When I did validation I have used **unique:users** . This way Laravel was not sure what column should be unique in table users. I should add 
**unique:users,username** to specify unique column username in user table.

[This article](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/requests/l-53-except-unique-validation-not-working) helped me.

Answer (score 0):

> Solutions : make sure write validation in double qoute like : "required"

```
 $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                    'client_id'     =>  "required",
                    'chapter_name'   =>  "required|unique:chapters",
                    ]
                );
               /** Return Error Message **/
        if ($validator->fails()) {
                    $error_msg  =   [];
                                foreach ( $validator->messages()->messages() as $key => $value) {
                      $error_msg[$key] =   $value[0];
                    } 
        }  print_r($error_msg);
```